# How to add multiple ID's in the ON function using JQUERY

Tags: jquery

This is my JQUERY CODE :

```
$("body").on("click keypress", "#admin-username",function(){
    if($("#admin-username").hasClass("error")){
        $("#admin-username").removeClass("error");
        setTimeout("$('.message').slideUp('slow');", 50);
    }
});
```

i have used an id `#admin-username` i.e only one id in the above JQuery code

where as in my Front-end code i have 3 input boxes

1.) `admin-username`
2.) `admin-email`
3.) `admin-password`

however i want to achieve something like this

```
$("body").on("click keypress", "#admin-username, #admin-password, #admin-email",function(){
    if($("#admin-username").hasClass("error")){
        $("#admin-username").removeClass("error");
        setTimeout("$('.message').slideUp('slow');", 50);
    }
});
```

But if i use multiple id's like this then by default it is working only for the first id i.e `#admin-username`

can anyone provide me a solution here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector is corrent but you need to use **this**-inside the callback function to access the element that raised the event

```
$("body").on("click keypress", "#admin-username, #admin-password, #admin-email",function()
        {
            if($(this).hasClass("error"))
                {
                    $(this).removeClass("error");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                      $('.message').slideUp('slow');
                     }, 50);
                }
        });
```

Also "corrected" the setTimeout with a callback-function.

Comment: Damn thanks a lot man, that code of your worked perfectly. I had some  more elements added. i had around 70 lines coded for that, this code just made it up-to 7 lines hardly. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem, remember to accept the answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

use the `this` variable to select the current clicked/keypressed element

```
$("body").on("click keypress", "#admin-username, #admin-password, #admin-email",function()
        {
            if($(this).hasClass("error"))
                {
                    $(this).removeClass("error");
                    setTimeout(function(){$('.message').slideUp('slow');}, 50);//here you should select the message div relative to the variable "this" like $(this).parent().find('.message').slideUp('slow');
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can add same class to the three inputs in your fontend code lets say adminInput, 
 second you can do something like this to eliminate the test you are making,

```
$("body").on("click keypress", ".adminInput.error",function(e)
    { var $this = $(this);

                $this.removeClass("error");
                 setTimeout(function(){$('.message').slideUp('slow');}, 50);

    });
```

you you can always do something like

```
$("#admin-password,#admin-username,#admin-email").click(function(e){ 
 var $this = $(this);       
 if($this.hasClass('error')){
       $this.removeClass("error");
       setTimeout(function(){$('.message').slideUp('slow');}, 50);
    }  
});
```

or

```
$("body").on("click keypress", "#admin-username,#admin-password,#admin-email",function(){
var $this = $(this);   
if($this.hasClass("error")){
    $this.removeClass("error");
    setTimeout(function(){$('.message').slideUp('slow');}, 50);
}
});
```

I modified the code so if you want  you can test the error class on any ids not just the username

Comment: isn't there any way to add multiple ID's

Answer (score 0):

You can target all id starting with admin like this. Instead of document you can have a container class/id where your elements are placed.

[Demo on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39o1fwm5/4/)

```
$(document).on('click keypress', '[id^=admin-]', function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.hasClass('error')) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: i didn't need this -_-

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav how is this different from the accepted answer? with this solution (and others) you use variable to store `this`.